# How to check if just one element of a vector is nonzero by a linear operator

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, matrix-equations, integer-programming

I want to check by a linear operator if none or just one element of a non-negative matrix is positive.
Consider a matrix $A$ as a $1\times N$ non-negative matrix and for each element $a_i \in A$ we have $0\leq a_i \leq A_{max}$.
$A$ is valid if it is all zero or it just has one none zero element like $A=(0, 2, 0, 0)$ or $A=(0, 0, 0, 5)$.
$A$ is not valid if it is like $A=(1, 0, 1, 0)$ as more than one element of A are non-zero.

I think normally it can be checked if $\sum_{i = 1}^{N} a_i = ||A||$ but this is not linear.

Is there any way to maybe multiply A into another matrix and check the result to see if $A$ is valid.
I am using $A$ in a integer linear optimization problem and having less than one non-zero element in $A$ is one of my constraints.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Counting nonzero elements in a MIP (Mixed Integer Program) is usually done by adding binary variables. Using your definition of $0\le a_i \le Amax$ we can write,

$$\begin{align}
  & a_i \le \delta_i \cdot Amax \\
  & \sum_i \delta_i \le 1 \\
  & \delta_i \in \{0,1\} 
\end{align}$$

The condition "maximum one nonzero" can also be achieved by using a SOS1 set. This will not require any additional binary variables. Many MIP solvers (but not all) have built-in support for Special Ordered Sets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is possible to do that by adding variables as you pointed out, but I wanted to see if I can do it without adding variables. I wanted to keep the variables as few as possible.