# Minimize the number of non-zero rows

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to formulate a shipping problem as a mathematical optimization one, and I'm having some trouble determining my optimization objective (cost function). Without getting too far into the details of the particular problem, the variable I am trying to optimize over is an $K\times N$ matrix X of non-negative integers. I have figured out some constraints on this matrix, namely $$ X^T \vec{1} = \vec{d} $$ and $$ X \preceq A $$ where $A$ is a non-negative $K\times N$ matrix of integers and $\vec{d}$ is a vector of length $N$ (of integers), and $\preceq$ indicates the usual component-wise matrix inequality. These are based on the particular problem at hand, and are nicely linear. This means I can plug these constraints into some numerical optimizer by simply "linearizing" the matrix $X$.

More complicatedly, as an objective I am trying to minimize a weighted count of non-zero rows of $X$. As such, I would like some sort of function `rowNonEmpty` which would take in a matrix row and return 0 if the row is all zeros and 1 otherwise. My optimization objective would then be something like
$$ \min_{X} \; \sum_{j=1}^K w_j \cdot \text{rowNonEmpty}\left(X_{j*}\right) $$ where $w_j$ is a weighting factor for row $j$ and $X_{j*}$ is the $j$th row of $X$.

Does anyone have some suggestions for how to properly frame this problem and the `rowNonEmpty` function? My first thought was that this is similar to some sort of weighted $L_1$ norm minimization, but not really because we are looking at non-zero rows of a matrix and not just vector entries. [The first answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889100/how-to-check-if-just-one-element-of-a-vector-is-nonzero-by-a-linear-operator) suggests adding binary variables, but this is again for a more standard problem involving only a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row $i$, introduce a binary variable $y_i$ to indicate whether the row is nonempty.  The objective is to minimize $\sum_i w_i y_i$, and the constraints are:
$$X_{i,j} \le A_{i,j} y_i$$
for each row $i$.
This formulation enforces the logical implication $X_{i,j} > 0 \implies y_i = 1$, which is sufficient if $w_i \ge 0$.

Comment: To be fully clear, I would now be optimizing over all of the variables $X$ _and_ $y$, with the original constraints still in play as well as this new one? The constraint and implication you stated otherwise make sense.

Comment: The $X \le A y$ constraints I added replace the original $X \le A$ constraints, but you still need the other original constraints.